Sharing based on Account Contact Relationships
I’ve enabled Account Contact Relationships in my Salesforce org, and I have a scenario where a Contact can be associated with multiple Accounts. To manage Case creation for these Accounts, I’ve created a role called "Cases". If a Contact has this role in their Account Contact Relationship (ACR), they should be able to create Cases for that particular Account in the Community. The license we are using for community is Customer Community Plus Login
Has anyone implemented a similar use case, or can suggest the best approach to achieve this?

One way:
Create a permission set with the desired permissions.
Then build automation (flow or Apex) to assign / unassign a community user, and triggered when the Role changes on the relation record.  The flow should create or delete the PermissionSetAssignment object.

how will permission set will control individual account level case access?

You'll need to provide more detail in your original post regarding your Org-wide Default sharing on Account and Case.  For the community user, can they view accounts for which they do not have the Cases role?  If so, then you'll need to build Flow automation on Case to prevent community users from creating cases when they don't have the role for the account.  You'd use the Fault action in Flow to do this.
